# Selenium returning empty list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to find *all* occurrences of a particular class on the webpage https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=York but selenium is just returning an empty list. The eventual aim is to extract the job title names of each position, but i can't seem to retrieve the initial data.

```
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=York'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)


jobs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard")

print(jobs)
```

I have also tried using `WebDriverWait` but i get no return again, not even an empty list but instead just nothing? Is it maybe something to do with the way i'm using the class name? As when i use the XPATH i can get some data back.

Here is the WebDriverWait code attempt.

```
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=York'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)


jobs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem, I think, is that you have spaces in the class name and that doesn't work right.  Instead of

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard")
```

I would try

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".jobsearch-SerpJobCard.unifiedRow.row.result.clickcard")
```